# Clean up Microsoft Exchange related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

The number of different tags for Microsoft Exchange-related tags is quite overwhelming:

- [exchange-2010](/questions/tagged/exchange-2010) is a synonym for [exchange2010](/questions/tagged/exchange2010) (111 questions)
- [exchange-2007](/questions/tagged/exchange-2007) is a synonym for [exchange2007](/questions/tagged/exchange2007) (187 questions)

So I guess the canonical version is `[exchangeYYYY]`. But then:

- [exchange-2003](/questions/tagged/exchange-2003) (64 questions) exists, but not [exchange2003](/questions/tagged/exchange2003)
- [exchange2007](/questions/tagged/exchange2007) (187 questions) doesn't have a [exchange-2007](/questions/tagged/exchange-2007)-synonym...

And, overall, regarding servers:

- [exchange-server](/questions/tagged/exchange-server) → [exchange](/questions/tagged/exchange)? (321 vs. 1017 questions respectively)
- [exchange-server-2010](/questions/tagged/exchange-server-2010) → [exchange2010](/questions/tagged/exchange2010) (17 vs. 111 questions)

Comment: I would prefer to see [exchange-server] be the canon tag, and I would prefer to see the year-specifc tags in the format [exchange-server-2010], personally

Answer (score 2):

I've taken care of this, in agreement with [LBT's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144773/clean-up-microsoft-exchange-related-tags#comment595595_144773). [exchange](/questions/tagged/exchange) is somewhat of an ambiguous word and I felt that [exchange-server](/questions/tagged/exchange-server) was much more suitable. The following synonyms now exist:

- [exchange-server](/questions/tagged/exchange-server) ← [exchange](/questions/tagged/exchange)
- [exchange-server-2003](/questions/tagged/exchange-server-2003) ← [exchange-2003](/questions/tagged/exchange-2003)
- [exchange-server-2007](/questions/tagged/exchange-server-2007) ← [exchange-2007](/questions/tagged/exchange-2007)
- [exchange-server-2010](/questions/tagged/exchange-server-2010) ← [exchange-2010](/questions/tagged/exchange-2010)

---

All of the stuff about the hyphenated version synonyms is not relevant. I got rid of all those a while ago as part of [my synonym cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147233/should-we-get-rid-of-all-the-tag-synonyms-which-differ-by-only-one-or-more-hyphe).