# Should we get rid of all the tag synonyms which differ by only one or more hyphens?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are tons of tags out there which have a synonym of the tag itself, just with a dash added into it. Originally this was done to connect those tags so that two different tags for the exact same thing didn't exist. But now [we have rules stopping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107002/) two tags from being created that only differ by a dash (or hyphen), so all these synonyms are useless.

Why? Searching for `foobar` and `foo-bar` yield the *exact* same results in the tag search. Whether or not the hyphen is there makes no difference, so the synonym doesn't actually serve any purpose anymore. It also clutters up the tags pages with extra tags that just redirect to another tag. With so little purpose, is it not safe to just ditch these crap synonyms? As well, any synonyms like this which have questions on both versions should be merged.

**Synonyms which only differ by a dash (including still-pending ones):**

- [.net-2.0](/questions/tagged/.net-2.0) ← [.net2.0](/questions/tagged/.net2.0)
- [.net-3.5](/questions/tagged/.net-3.5) ← [.net3.5](/questions/tagged/.net3.5)
- [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) ← [.net4.0](/questions/tagged/.net4.0)
- [.net-remoting](/questions/tagged/.net-remoting) ← [.netremoting](/questions/tagged/.netremoting)
- [.net-services](/questions/tagged/.net-services) ← [.netservices](/questions/tagged/.netservices)
- [16bit](/questions/tagged/16bit) ← [16-bit](/questions/tagged/16-bit)
- [32bit](/questions/tagged/32bit) ← [32-bit](/questions/tagged/32-bit)
- [3d-secure](/questions/tagged/3d-secure) ← [3dsecure](/questions/tagged/3dsecure)
- [3rd-party](/questions/tagged/3rd-party) ← [3rdparty](/questions/tagged/3rdparty)
- [64bit](/questions/tagged/64bit) ← [64-bit](/questions/tagged/64-bit)
- [ab-testing](/questions/tagged/ab-testing) ← [abtesting](/questions/tagged/abtesting)
- [access-denied](/questions/tagged/access-denied) ← [accessdenied](/questions/tagged/accessdenied)
- [access-point](/questions/tagged/access-point) ← [accesspoint](/questions/tagged/accesspoint)
- [action-filter](/questions/tagged/action-filter) ← [actionfilter](/questions/tagged/actionfilter)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [actionfilters](/questions/tagged/actionfilters) since [action-filters](/questions/tagged/action-filters) covers it.
- [actionmailer](/questions/tagged/actionmailer) ← [action-mailer](/questions/tagged/action-mailer)
- [actionmethod](/questions/tagged/actionmethod) ← [action-method](/questions/tagged/action-method)
- [activerecord](/questions/tagged/activerecord) ← [active-record](/questions/tagged/active-record)
- [add-in](/questions/tagged/add-in) ← [addin](/questions/tagged/addin)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [addins](/questions/tagged/addins) since [add-ins](/questions/tagged/add-ins) covers it.
- [add-on](/questions/tagged/add-on) ← [addon](/questions/tagged/addon)
- [addressbook](/questions/tagged/addressbook) ← [address-book](/questions/tagged/address-book)
- [ajaxpro](/questions/tagged/ajaxpro) ← [ajax-pro](/questions/tagged/ajax-pro)
- [amazon-cloudfront](/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudfront) ← [amazon-cloud-front](/questions/tagged/amazon-cloud-front)
- [anti-patterns](/questions/tagged/anti-patterns) ← [antipatterns](/questions/tagged/antipatterns)
- [app-config](/questions/tagged/app-config) ← [appconfig](/questions/tagged/appconfig)
- [app-store](/questions/tagged/app-store) ← [appstore](/questions/tagged/appstore)
- [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) ← [asp.netmvc](/questions/tagged/asp.netmvc)
- [asp.net-mvc-2](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-2) ← [asp.net-mvc2](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc2)
- [asp.net-mvc-3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) ← [asp.net-mvc3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc3)
- [a-star](/questions/tagged/a-star) ← [astar](/questions/tagged/astar)
- [attached-properties](/questions/tagged/attached-properties) ← [attachedproperties](/questions/tagged/attachedproperties)
- [autocomplete](/questions/tagged/autocomplete) ← [auto-complete](/questions/tagged/auto-complete)
- [auto-generate](/questions/tagged/auto-generate) ← [autogenerate](/questions/tagged/autogenerate)
- [auto-properties](/questions/tagged/auto-properties) ← [autoproperties](/questions/tagged/autoproperties)
- [autosuggest](/questions/tagged/autosuggest) ← [auto-suggest](/questions/tagged/auto-suggest)
- [back-button](/questions/tagged/back-button) ← [backbutton](/questions/tagged/backbutton)
- [background-color](/questions/tagged/background-color) ← [backgroundcolor](/questions/tagged/backgroundcolor)
- [bar-chart](/questions/tagged/bar-chart) ← [barchart](/questions/tagged/barchart)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [bargraph](/questions/tagged/bargraph) since [bar-graph](/questions/tagged/bar-graph) covers it.
- [base-address](/questions/tagged/base-address) ← [baseaddress](/questions/tagged/baseaddress)
- [base-class](/questions/tagged/base-class) ← [baseclass](/questions/tagged/baseclass)
- [batch-processing](/questions/tagged/batch-processing) ← [batchprocessing](/questions/tagged/batchprocessing)
- [berkeley-db](/questions/tagged/berkeley-db) ← [berkeleydb](/questions/tagged/berkeleydb)
- [berkeley-db-je](/questions/tagged/berkeley-db-je) ← [berkeleydbje](/questions/tagged/berkeleydbje)
- [berkeley-db-je](/questions/tagged/berkeley-db-je) ← [berkeleydb-je](/questions/tagged/berkeleydb-je)
- [beta-testing](/questions/tagged/beta-testing) ← [betatesting](/questions/tagged/betatesting)
- [binary-data](/questions/tagged/binary-data) ← [binarydata](/questions/tagged/binarydata)
- [bit-fields](/questions/tagged/bit-fields) ← [bitfields](/questions/tagged/bitfields)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [bitfield](/questions/tagged/bitfield) since [bit-field](/questions/tagged/bit-field) covers it.
- [b-tree](/questions/tagged/b-tree) ← [btree](/questions/tagged/btree)
- [bug-tracking](/questions/tagged/bug-tracking) ← [bugtracking](/questions/tagged/bugtracking)
- [bytearray](/questions/tagged/bytearray) ← [byte-array](/questions/tagged/byte-array)
- [bytecode](/questions/tagged/bytecode) ← [byte-code](/questions/tagged/byte-code)
- [c++builder-5](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bbuilder-5) ← [c++-builder-5](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-builder-5)
- [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) ← [c++cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bcli)
- [cache-dependency](/questions/tagged/cache-dependency) ← [cachedependency](/questions/tagged/cachedependency)
- [casting](/questions/tagged/casting) (eliminate [typecasting](/questions/tagged/typecasting) since [type-casting](/questions/tagged/type-casting) covers it)
- [changelog](/questions/tagged/changelog) ← [change-log](/questions/tagged/change-log)
- [char-array](/questions/tagged/char-array) ← [chararray](/questions/tagged/chararray)
- [classloader](/questions/tagged/classloader) (eliminate [classloading](/questions/tagged/classloading) since [class-loading](/questions/tagged/class-loading) covers it)
- [class-method](/questions/tagged/class-method) ← [classmethod](/questions/tagged/classmethod)
- [client-profile](/questions/tagged/client-profile) ← [clientprofile](/questions/tagged/clientprofile)
- [client-server](/questions/tagged/client-server) ← [clientserver](/questions/tagged/clientserver)
- [cluster-analysis](/questions/tagged/cluster-analysis) (eliminate [dataclustering](/questions/tagged/dataclustering) since [data-clustering](/questions/tagged/data-clustering) covers it)
- [code-first](/questions/tagged/code-first) ← [codefirst](/questions/tagged/codefirst)
- [code-smell](/questions/tagged/code-smell) ← [codesmell](/questions/tagged/codesmell)
- [code-snippets](/questions/tagged/code-snippets) ← [codesnippets](/questions/tagged/codesnippets)
- [color-space](/questions/tagged/color-space) ← [colorspace](/questions/tagged/colorspace)
- [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) ← [commandline](/questions/tagged/commandline)
- [common-table-expression](/questions/tagged/common-table-expression) ← [commontableexpression](/questions/tagged/commontableexpression)
- [connection-string](/questions/tagged/connection-string) ← [connectionstring](/questions/tagged/connectionstring)
- [core-animation](/questions/tagged/core-animation) ← [coreanimation](/questions/tagged/coreanimation)
- [core-audio](/questions/tagged/core-audio) ← [coreaudio](/questions/tagged/coreaudio)
- [code-data](/questions/tagged/code-data) ← [coredata](/questions/tagged/coredata)
- [core-foundation](/questions/tagged/core-foundation) ← [corefoundation](/questions/tagged/corefoundation)
- [core-graphics](/questions/tagged/core-graphics) ← [coregraphics](/questions/tagged/coregraphics)
- [core-location](/questions/tagged/core-location) ← [corelocation](/questions/tagged/corelocation)
- [core-plot](/questions/tagged/core-plot) ← [coreplot](/questions/tagged/coreplot)
- [core-text](/questions/tagged/core-text) ← [coretext](/questions/tagged/coretext)
- [credit-card](/questions/tagged/credit-card) (eliminate [creditcards](/questions/tagged/creditcards) since [credit-cards](/questions/tagged/credit-cards) covers it)
- [cross-platform](/questions/tagged/cross-platform) ← [crossplatform](/questions/tagged/crossplatform)
- [crystal-reports](/questions/tagged/crystal-reports) (eliminate [crystalreport](/questions/tagged/crystalreport) since [crystal-report](/questions/tagged/crystal-report) covers it)
- [custom-action](/questions/tagged/custom-action) ← [customaction](/questions/tagged/customaction)
- [custom-component](/questions/tagged/custom-component) ← [customcomponent](/questions/tagged/customcomponent)
- [custom-controls](/questions/tagged/custom-controls) ← [customcontrols](/questions/tagged/customcontrols)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [customcontrol](/questions/tagged/customcontrol) since [custom-control](/questions/tagged/custom-control) covers it.
- [custom-errors](/questions/tagged/custom-errors) ← [customerrors](/questions/tagged/customerrors)
- [custom-model-binder](/questions/tagged/custom-model-binder) ← [custom-modelbinder](/questions/tagged/custom-modelbinder)
- [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame) (eliminate [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) since [data-frame](/questions/tagged/data-frame) covers it)
- [data-access-layer](/questions/tagged/data-access-layer) ← [dataaccesslayer](/questions/tagged/dataaccesslayer)
- [data-binding](/questions/tagged/data-binding) ← [databinding](/questions/tagged/databinding)
- [datagrid](/questions/tagged/datagrid) ← [data-grid](/questions/tagged/data-grid)
- [data-mining](/questions/tagged/data-mining) ← [datamining](/questions/tagged/datamining)
- [datasource](/questions/tagged/datasource) ← [data-source](/questions/tagged/data-source)
- [data-structures](/questions/tagged/data-structures) ← [datastructures](/questions/tagged/datastructures)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [datastructure](/questions/tagged/datastructure) since [data-structure](/questions/tagged/data-structure) covers it.
- [data-synchronization](/questions/tagged/data-synchronization) ← [datasynchronization](/questions/tagged/datasynchronization)
- [datatypes](/questions/tagged/datatypes) ← [data-types](/questions/tagged/data-types)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [data-type](/questions/tagged/data-type) since [datatype](/questions/tagged/datatype) covers it.
- [data-warehouse](/questions/tagged/data-warehouse) ← [datawarehouse](/questions/tagged/datawarehouse)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [datawarehousing](/questions/tagged/datawarehousing) since [data-warehousing](/questions/tagged/data-warehousing) covers it.
- [datetime](/questions/tagged/datetime) ← [date-time](/questions/tagged/date-time)
- [dbix-class](/questions/tagged/dbix-class) ← [dbixclass](/questions/tagged/dbixclass)
- [diffie-hellman](/questions/tagged/diffie-hellman) ← [diffiehellman](/questions/tagged/diffiehellman)
- [distributed-transactions](/questions/tagged/distributed-transactions) ← [distributedtransactions](/questions/tagged/distributedtransactions)
- [domain-name](/questions/tagged/domain-name) ← [domainname](/questions/tagged/domainname)
- [dot-emacs](/questions/tagged/dot-emacs) ← [dotemacs](/questions/tagged/dotemacs)
- [dotnetnuke-5](/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-5) ← [dotnetnuke5](/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke5)
- [double-click](/questions/tagged/double-click) ← [doubleclick](/questions/tagged/doubleclick)
- [double-quotes](/questions/tagged/double-quotes) ← [doublequotes](/questions/tagged/doublequotes)
- [drag-and-drop](/questions/tagged/drag-and-drop) ← [draganddrop](/questions/tagged/draganddrop)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [dragdrop](/questions/tagged/dragdrop) since [drag-drop](/questions/tagged/drag-drop) covers it.
- [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) ← [dropdown-menu](/questions/tagged/dropdown-menu)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [dropdown](/questions/tagged/dropdown) since [drop-down](/questions/tagged/drop-down) covers it.
- [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7) ← [drupal7](/questions/tagged/drupal7)
- [dynamic-binding](/questions/tagged/dynamic-binding) ← [dynamicbinding](/questions/tagged/dynamicbinding)
- [dynamic-linq](/questions/tagged/dynamic-linq) ← [dynamiclinq](/questions/tagged/dynamiclinq)
- [early-binding](/questions/tagged/early-binding) ← [earlybinding](/questions/tagged/earlybinding)
- [ebook](/questions/tagged/ebook) ← [e-book](/questions/tagged/e-book)
- [e-commerce](/questions/tagged/e-commerce) ← [ecommerce](/questions/tagged/ecommerce)
- [ejb-3.0](/questions/tagged/ejb-3.0) ← [ejb3.0](/questions/tagged/ejb3.0)
- [ejb-3.1](/questions/tagged/ejb-3.1) ← [ejb3.1](/questions/tagged/ejb3.1)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [ejb31](/questions/tagged/ejb31) and [ejb-31](/questions/tagged/ejb-31); 3.1 != 31
- [elasticsearh](/questions/tagged/elasticsearh) ← [elastic-search](/questions/tagged/elastic-search)
- [electric-commander](/questions/tagged/electric-commander) ← [electriccommander](/questions/tagged/electriccommander)
- [emacs23](/questions/tagged/emacs23) ← [emacs-23](/questions/tagged/emacs-23)
- [email](/questions/tagged/email) ← [e-mail](/questions/tagged/e-mail)
- [ember-data](/questions/tagged/ember-data) ← [emberdata](/questions/tagged/emberdata)
- [entity-framework-4](/questions/tagged/entity-framework-4) ← [entity-framework4](/questions/tagged/entity-framework4)
- [error-code](/questions/tagged/error-code) ← [errorcode](/questions/tagged/errorcode)
- [event-handling](/questions/tagged/event-handling) ← [eventhandling](/questions/tagged/eventhandling)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [eventhandler](/questions/tagged/eventhandler) since [event-handler](/questions/tagged/event-handler) covers it.
- [event-log](/questions/tagged/event-log) ← [eventlog](/questions/tagged/eventlog)
- [exchange2007](/questions/tagged/exchange2007) ← [exchange-2007](/questions/tagged/exchange-2007)
- [exchange2010](/questions/tagged/exchange2010) ← [exchange-2010](/questions/tagged/exchange-2010)
- [expressionengine](/questions/tagged/expressionengine) ← [expression-engine](/questions/tagged/expression-engine)
- [ext-gwt](/questions/tagged/ext-gwt) ← [extgwt](/questions/tagged/extgwt)
- [facebook-connect](/questions/tagged/facebook-connect) ← [facebookconnect](/questions/tagged/facebookconnect)
  **Note:** Also eliminate improperly spelled [facebook-connnect](/questions/tagged/facebook-connnect).
- [file-descriptor](/questions/tagged/file-descriptor) ← [filedescriptor](/questions/tagged/filedescriptor)
- [file-download](/questions/tagged/file-download) ← [filedownload](/questions/tagged/filedownload)
- [file-io](/questions/tagged/file-io) ← [fileio](/questions/tagged/fileio)
- [filenames](/questions/tagged/filenames) ← [file-names](/questions/tagged/file-names)
- [file-permissions](/questions/tagged/file-permissions) ← [filepermissions](/questions/tagged/filepermissions)
- [file-type](/questions/tagged/file-type) ← [filetype](/questions/tagged/filetype)
- [file-upload](/questions/tagged/file-upload) ← [fileupload](/questions/tagged/fileupload)
- [firefox-3](/questions/tagged/firefox-3) ← [firefox3](/questions/tagged/firefox3)
- [flash-cs5](/questions/tagged/flash-cs5) ← [flashcs5](/questions/tagged/flashcs5)
- [flash-media-server](/questions/tagged/flash-media-server) ← [flashmediaserver](/questions/tagged/flashmediaserver)
- [flash-player](/questions/tagged/flash-player) ← [flashplayer](/questions/tagged/flashplayer)
- [flex4](/questions/tagged/flex4) ← [flex-4](/questions/tagged/flex-4)
  **Note:** [flex-4](/questions/tagged/flex-4) is also the master of [adobe-flex-4](/questions/tagged/adobe-flex-4).
- [fluent-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/fluent-nhibernate) ← [fluentnhibernate](/questions/tagged/fluentnhibernate)
- [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach) ← [for-each](/questions/tagged/for-each)
- [foreign-keys](/questions/tagged/foreign-keys) (eliminate [foreignkey](/questions/tagged/foreignkey) since [foreign-key](/questions/tagged/foreign-key) covers it)
- [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) ← [forloop](/questions/tagged/forloop)
- [for-xml](/questions/tagged/for-xml) ← [forxml](/questions/tagged/forxml)
- [frame-rate](/questions/tagged/frame-rate) ← [framerate](/questions/tagged/framerate)
- [fullscreen](/questions/tagged/fullscreen) ← [full-screen](/questions/tagged/full-screen)
- [full-text-search](/questions/tagged/full-text-search) ← [fulltext-search](/questions/tagged/fulltext-search)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [fulltext](/questions/tagged/fulltext) since [full-text](/questions/tagged/full-text) covers it.
- [full-trust](/questions/tagged/full-trust) ← [fulltrust](/questions/tagged/fulltrust)
- [git-extensions](/questions/tagged/git-extensions) ← [gitextensions](/questions/tagged/gitextensions)
- [glassfish-3](/questions/tagged/glassfish-3) ← [glassfish3](/questions/tagged/glassfish3)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [glassfishv3](/questions/tagged/glassfishv3) since [glassfish-v3](/questions/tagged/glassfish-v3) covers it.
- [gnu-make](/questions/tagged/gnu-make) ← [gnumake](/questions/tagged/gnumake)
- [google-api](/questions/tagged/google-api) ← [googleapi](/questions/tagged/googleapi)
- [google-code](/questions/tagged/google-code) ← [googlecode](/questions/tagged/googlecode)
- [google-docs](/questions/tagged/google-docs) ← [googledocs](/questions/tagged/googledocs)
- [google-earth](/questions/tagged/google-earth) ← [google-earth](/questions/tagged/google-earth)
- [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps) ← [googlemaps](/questions/tagged/googlemaps)
- [group-by](/questions/tagged/group-by) ← [groupby](/questions/tagged/groupby)
- [gwt](/questions/tagged/gwt) (eliminate [googlewebtoolkit](/questions/tagged/googlewebtoolkit) since [google-web-toolkit](/questions/tagged/google-web-toolkit) covers it)
- [gwt-ext](/questions/tagged/gwt-ext) ← [gwtext](/questions/tagged/gwtext)
- [harddrive](/questions/tagged/harddrive) ← [hard-drive](/questions/tagged/hard-drive)
- [hashmap](/questions/tagged/hashmap) ← [hash-map](/questions/tagged/hash-map)
- [has-one](/questions/tagged/has-one) ← [hasone](/questions/tagged/hasone)
- [header-files](/questions/tagged/header-files) (eliminate [headerfile](/questions/tagged/headerfile) since [header-file](/questions/tagged/header-file) covers it)
- [hittest](/questions/tagged/hittest) ← [hit-test](/questions/tagged/hit-test)
- [howto](/questions/tagged/howto) ← [how-to](/questions/tagged/how-to)
- [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) ← [html-5](/questions/tagged/html-5)
- [html-agility-pack](/questions/tagged/html-agility-pack) ← [htmlagilitypack](/questions/tagged/htmlagilitypack)
- [html-editor](/questions/tagged/html-editor) ← [htmleditor](/questions/tagged/htmleditor)
- [html-helper](/questions/tagged/html-helper) ← [htmlhelper](/questions/tagged/htmlhelper)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [htmlhelpers](/questions/tagged/htmlhelpers) since [html-helpers](/questions/tagged/html-helpers) covers it.
- [http-1.1](/questions/tagged/http-1.1) ← [http1.1](/questions/tagged/http1.1)
- [http-compression](/questions/tagged/http-compression) ← [httpcompression](/questions/tagged/httpcompression)
- [httpconnection](/questions/tagged/httpconnection) ← [http-connection](/questions/tagged/http-connection)
- [httpcontext](/questions/tagged/httpcontext) ← [http-context](/questions/tagged/http-context)
- [http-get](/questions/tagged/http-get) ← [httpget](/questions/tagged/httpget)
- [iis7](/questions/tagged/iis7) ← [iis-7](/questions/tagged/iis-7)
- [iis-7.5](/questions/tagged/iis-7.5) ← [iis7.5](/questions/tagged/iis7.5)
- [imagebutton](/questions/tagged/imagebutton) ← [image-button](/questions/tagged/image-button)
- [imagemap](/questions/tagged/imagemap) ← [image-map](/questions/tagged/image-map)
- [internet-explorer-6](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-6) ← [internet-explorer6](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer6)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [ie6](/questions/tagged/ie6) since [ie-6](/questions/tagged/ie-6) covers it.
- [internet-explorer-7](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-7) ← [internet-explorer7](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer7)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [ie7](/questions/tagged/ie7) since [ie-7](/questions/tagged/ie-7) covers it.
- [internet-explorer-8](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-8) ← [internet-explorer8](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer8)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [ie8](/questions/tagged/ie8) since [ie-8](/questions/tagged/ie-8) covers it.
- [internet-explorer-9](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-9) ← [internet-explorer9](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer9)
- [iolanguage](/questions/tagged/iolanguage) ← [io-language](/questions/tagged/io-language)
- [ios4](/questions/tagged/ios4) ← [ios-4](/questions/tagged/ios-4)
- [ios-4.2](/questions/tagged/ios-4.2) ← [ios4.2](/questions/tagged/ios4.2)
- [ipad-2](/questions/tagged/ipad-2) ← [ipad2](/questions/tagged/ipad2)
- [ip-address](/questions/tagged/ip-address) ← [ipaddress](/questions/tagged/ipaddress)
- [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) (eliminate [iphonesdk](/questions/tagged/iphonesdk) since [iphone-sdk](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk) covers it)
- [iphone-4](/questions/tagged/iphone-4) ← [iphone4](/questions/tagged/iphone4)
- [iphone-sdk-3](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-3) ← [iphone-sdk3](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk3)
- [ipod-touch](/questions/tagged/ipod-touch) ← [ipodtouch](/questions/tagged/ipodtouch)
- [iso8601](/questions/tagged/iso8601) ← [iso-8601](/questions/tagged/iso-8601)
- [jasper-reports](/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) ← [jasperreports](/questions/tagged/jasperreports)
- [java](/questions/tagged/java) (eliminate [javase](/questions/tagged/javase) since [java-se](/questions/tagged/java-se) covers it)
- [java-1.3](/questions/tagged/java-1.3) ← [java1.3](/questions/tagged/java1.3)
- [java-1.4](/questions/tagged/java-1.4) ← [java14](/questions/tagged/java14) (14 != 1.4)
- [java-2d](/questions/tagged/java-2d) ← [java2d](/questions/tagged/java2d)
- [java-3d](/questions/tagged/java-3d) ← [java3d](/questions/tagged/java3d)
- [java-5](/questions/tagged/java-5) ← [java5](/questions/tagged/java5)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [java5.0](/questions/tagged/java5.0) since [java-5.0](/questions/tagged/java-5.0) covers it.
- [java-6](/questions/tagged/java-6) ← [java6](/questions/tagged/java6)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [java6.0](/questions/tagged/java6.0) since [java-6.0](/questions/tagged/java-6.0) covers it.
- [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7) ← [java7](/questions/tagged/java7)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [java7.0](/questions/tagged/java7.0) since [java-7.0](/questions/tagged/java-7.0) covers it.
- [javadb](/questions/tagged/javadb) ← [java-db](/questions/tagged/java-db)
- [java-ee](/questions/tagged/java-ee) ← [javaee](/questions/tagged/javaee)
- [java-ee-5](/questions/tagged/java-ee-5) ← [javaee5](/questions/tagged/javaee5)
- [java-ee-5](/questions/tagged/java-ee-5) ← [javaee-5](/questions/tagged/javaee-5)
- [java-ee-5](/questions/tagged/java-ee-5) ← [java-ee5](/questions/tagged/java-ee5)
- [java-ee-6](/questions/tagged/java-ee-6) ← [javaee6](/questions/tagged/javaee6)
- [java-ee-6](/questions/tagged/java-ee-6) ← [javaee-6](/questions/tagged/javaee-6)
- [java-ee-6](/questions/tagged/java-ee-6) ← [java-ee6](/questions/tagged/java-ee6)
- [java-io](/questions/tagged/java-io) ← [javaio](/questions/tagged/javaio)
- [java-me](/questions/tagged/java-me) ← [javame](/questions/tagged/javame)
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) ← [java-script](/questions/tagged/java-script)
- [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) ← [javawebstart](/questions/tagged/javawebstart)
- [jax-rs](/questions/tagged/jax-rs) ← [jaxrs](/questions/tagged/jaxrs)
- [jax-ws](/questions/tagged/jax-ws) ← [jaxws](/questions/tagged/jaxws)
- [jpa-2.0](/questions/tagged/jpa-2.0) ← [jpa2.0](/questions/tagged/jpa2.0)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [jpa2](/questions/tagged/jpa2) since [jpa-2](/questions/tagged/jpa-2) covers it.
- [jquery-1.4](/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4) ← [jquery1.4](/questions/tagged/jquery1.4)
- [jquery-1.5](/questions/tagged/jquery-1.5) ← [jquery1.5](/questions/tagged/jquery1.5)
- [jquery-grid](/questions/tagged/jquery-grid) ← [jquerygrid](/questions/tagged/jquerygrid)
- [jquery-tools](/questions/tagged/jquery-tools) ← [jquerytools](/questions/tagged/jquerytools)
- [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui) ← [jqueryui](/questions/tagged/jqueryui)
- [jsf-2.0](/questions/tagged/jsf-2.0) ← [jsf2.0](/questions/tagged/jsf2.0)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [jsf2](/questions/tagged/jsf2) since [jsf-2](/questions/tagged/jsf-2) covers it.
- [jsp-fragments](/questions/tagged/jsp-fragments) ← [jspfragments](/questions/tagged/jspfragments)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [jspfragment](/questions/tagged/jspfragment) since [jsp-fragment](/questions/tagged/jsp-fragment) covers it.
- [jsp-tags](/questions/tagged/jsp-tags) (eliminate [jsptagfiles](/questions/tagged/jsptagfiles) since [jsp-tag-files](/questions/tagged/jsp-tag-files) covers it)
- [kendo-ui](/questions/tagged/kendo-ui) ← [kendoui](/questions/tagged/kendoui)
- [key-bindings](/questions/tagged/key-bindings) ← [keybindings](/questions/tagged/keybindings)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [keybinding](/questions/tagged/keybinding) since [key-binding](/questions/tagged/key-binding) covers it.
- [key-value](/questions/tagged/key-value) ← [keyvalue](/questions/tagged/keyvalue)
- [layout-manager](/questions/tagged/layout-manager) ← [layoutmanager](/questions/tagged/layoutmanager)
- [line-break](/questions/tagged/line-break) ← [linebreak](/questions/tagged/linebreak)
- [line-breaks](/questions/tagged/line-breaks) ← [linebreaks](/questions/tagged/linebreaks)
- [linkbutton](/questions/tagged/linkbutton) ← [link-button](/questions/tagged/link-button)
- [linked-list](/questions/tagged/linked-list) ← [linkedlist](/questions/tagged/linkedlist)
- [linq-to-sql](/questions/tagged/linq-to-sql) ← [linqtosql](/questions/tagged/linqtosql)
- [llvmclang](/questions/tagged/llvmclang) ← [llvm-clang](/questions/tagged/llvm-clang)
- [load-balancing](/questions/tagged/load-balancing) ← [loadbalancing](/questions/tagged/loadbalancing)
- [local-lib](/questions/tagged/local-lib) ← [locallib](/questions/tagged/locallib)
- [local-storage](/questions/tagged/local-storage) ← [localstorage](/questions/tagged/localstorage)
- [lowercase](/questions/tagged/lowercase) ← [lower-case](/questions/tagged/lower-case)
- [mac-address](/questions/tagged/mac-address) ← [macaddress](/questions/tagged/macaddress)
- [many-to-many](/questions/tagged/many-to-many) ← [manytomany](/questions/tagged/manytomany)
- [maven-2](/questions/tagged/maven-2) ← [maven2](/questions/tagged/maven2)
- [mediaplayer](/questions/tagged/mediaplayer) ← [media-player](/questions/tagged/media-player)
- [media-queries](/questions/tagged/media-queries) ← [mediaqueries](/questions/tagged/mediaqueries)
- [memory-leaks](/questions/tagged/memory-leaks) (eliminate [memoryleak](/questions/tagged/memoryleak) since [memory-leak](/questions/tagged/memory-leak) covers it)
- [message-passing](/questions/tagged/message-passing) ← [messagepassing](/questions/tagged/messagepassing)
- [message-queue](/questions/tagged/message-queue) ← [messagequeue](/questions/tagged/messagequeue)
- [metaprogramming](/questions/tagged/metaprogramming) ← [meta-programming](/questions/tagged/meta-programming)
- [method-call](/questions/tagged/method-call) ← [methodcall](/questions/tagged/methodcall)
- [method-overloading](/questions/tagged/method-overloading) ← [methodoverloading](/questions/tagged/methodoverloading)
- [micro-isv](/questions/tagged/micro-isv) ← [microisv](/questions/tagged/microisv)
- [mime-message](/questions/tagged/mime-message) ← [mimemessage](/questions/tagged/mimemessage)
- [mime-types](/questions/tagged/mime-types) ← [mimetypes](/questions/tagged/mimetypes)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [mimetype](/questions/tagged/mimetype) since [mime-type](/questions/tagged/mime-type) covers it.
- [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) ← [mobileweb](/questions/tagged/mobileweb)
- [modalviewcontroller](/questions/tagged/modalviewcontroller) ← [modal-view-controller](/questions/tagged/modal-view-controller)
- [mpeg-4](/questions/tagged/mpeg-4) ← [mpeg4](/questions/tagged/mpeg4)
- [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) ← [msaccess](/questions/tagged/msaccess)
- [ms-word](/questions/tagged/ms-word) ← [msword](/questions/tagged/msword)
- [multibyte](/questions/tagged/multibyte) ← [multi-byte](/questions/tagged/multi-byte)
- [multi-select](/questions/tagged/multi-select) ← [multiselect](/questions/tagged/multiselect)
- [multi-site](/questions/tagged/multi-site) ← [multisite](/questions/tagged/multisite)
- [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) ← [multi-threading](/questions/tagged/multi-threading)
- [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) ← [my-sql](/questions/tagged/my-sql)
- [nested-sets](/questions/tagged/nested-sets) ← [nestedsets](/questions/tagged/nestedsets)
- [netbeans-6.9](/questions/tagged/netbeans-6.9) ← [neatbeans6.9](/questions/tagged/neatbeans6.9)
- [nine-patch](/questions/tagged/nine-patch) ← [ninepatch](/questions/tagged/ninepatch)
- [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) (eliminate [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) since [node-js](/questions/tagged/node-js) covers it)
- [no-framework](/questions/tagged/no-framework) ← [noframework](/questions/tagged/noframework)
- [nonblocking](/questions/tagged/nonblocking) ← [non-blocking](/questions/tagged/non-blocking)
- [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) (eliminate [objc](/questions/tagged/objc) since [obj-c](/questions/tagged/obj-c) covers it)
- [one-to-one](/questions/tagged/one-to-one) ← [onetoone](/questions/tagged/onetoone)
- [opengl-es](/questions/tagged/opengl-es) ← [opengles](/questions/tagged/opengles)
- [opensearch](/questions/tagged/opensearch) ← [oopen-search](/questions/tagged/oopen-search)
- [oracleforms](/questions/tagged/oracleforms) ← [oracle-forms](/questions/tagged/oracle-forms)
- [oracle-xe](/questions/tagged/oracle-xe) ← [oraclexe](/questions/tagged/oraclexe)
- [order-by](/questions/tagged/order-by) ← [orderby](/questions/tagged/orderby)
- [orient-db](/questions/tagged/orient-db) ← [orientdb](/questions/tagged/orientdb)
- [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) (eliminate [macosx](/questions/tagged/macosx) since [mac-os-x](/questions/tagged/mac-os-x) covers it)
- [passive-sts](/questions/tagged/passive-sts) ← [passivests](/questions/tagged/passivests)
- [path-finding](/questions/tagged/path-finding) ← [pathfinding](/questions/tagged/pathfinding)
- [perl-critic](/questions/tagged/perl-critic) ← [perlcritic](/questions/tagged/perlcritic)
- [perl-tidy](/questions/tagged/perl-tidy) ← [perltidy](/questions/tagged/perltidy)
- [phone-number](/questions/tagged/phone-number) (eliminate [phonenumbers](/questions/tagged/phonenumbers) since [phone-numbers](/questions/tagged/phone-numbers) covers it)
- [tagphp-5.2] ← [php52](/questions/tagged/php52) (52 != 5.2)
- [pie-chart](/questions/tagged/pie-chart) ← [piechart](/questions/tagged/piechart)
- [pinvoke](/questions/tagged/pinvoke) ← [p-invoke](/questions/tagged/p-invoke)
- [pixel-bender](/questions/tagged/pixel-bender) ← [pixelbender](/questions/tagged/pixelbender)
- [playframework](/questions/tagged/playframework) ← [play-framework](/questions/tagged/play-framework)
- [plsql](/questions/tagged/plsql) ← [pl-sql](/questions/tagged/pl-sql)
- [plugins](/questions/tagged/plugins) ← [plug-ins](/questions/tagged/plug-ins)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [plug-in](/questions/tagged/plug-in) since [plugin](/questions/tagged/plugin) covers it.
- [prepared-statement](/questions/tagged/prepared-statement) ← [preparedstatement](/questions/tagged/preparedstatement)
- [primary-key](/questions/tagged/primary-key) ← [primarykey](/questions/tagged/primarykey)
- [profiling](/questions/tagged/profiling) (eliminate [profilingtools](/questions/tagged/profilingtools) since [profiling-tools](/questions/tagged/profiling-tools) covers it)
- [progress-bar](/questions/tagged/progress-bar) ← [progressbar](/questions/tagged/progressbar)
- [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) (eliminate [python2](/questions/tagged/python2) since [python-2](/questions/tagged/python-2) covers it)
- [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (eliminate [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) since [python-3](/questions/tagged/python-3) covers it)
- [qt-creator](/questions/tagged/qt-creator) ← [qtcreator](/questions/tagged/qtcreator)
- [qt-designer](/questions/tagged/qt-designer) ← [qtdesigner](/questions/tagged/qtdesigner)
- [quartz-2d](/questions/tagged/quartz-2d) ← [quartz2d](/questions/tagged/quartz2d)
- [query-string](/questions/tagged/query-string) ← [querystring](/questions/tagged/querystring)
- [quoted-identifier](/questions/tagged/quoted-identifier) ← [quotedidentifier](/questions/tagged/quotedidentifier)
- [radio-button](/questions/tagged/radio-button) ← [radiobutton](/questions/tagged/radiobutton)
- [raw-input](/questions/tagged/raw-input) ← [rawinput](/questions/tagged/rawinput)
- [real-estate](/questions/tagged/real-estate) ← [realestate](/questions/tagged/realestate)
- [real-mode](/questions/tagged/real-mode) ← [realmode](/questions/tagged/realmode)
- [real-time](/questions/tagged/real-time) ← [realtime](/questions/tagged/realtime)
- [redhat](/questions/tagged/redhat) ← [red-hat](/questions/tagged/red-hat)
- [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) (eliminate [regularexpression](/questions/tagged/regularexpression) since [regular-expression](/questions/tagged/regular-expression) covers it)
- [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) (eliminate [regularexpressions](/questions/tagged/regularexpressions) since [regular-expressions](/questions/tagged/regular-expressions) covers it)
- [reporting-services](/questions/tagged/reporting-services) ← [reportingservices](/questions/tagged/reportingservices)
- [reportingservices-2005](/questions/tagged/reportingservices-2005) ← [reporting-services-2005](/questions/tagged/reporting-services-2005)
- [reportingservices-2005](/questions/tagged/reportingservices-2005) ← [reportingservices2005](/questions/tagged/reportingservices2005)
- [reportingservices-2008](/questions/tagged/reportingservices-2008) ← [reporting-services-2008](/questions/tagged/reporting-services-2008)
- [reportviewer](/questions/tagged/reportviewer) ← [report-viewer](/questions/tagged/report-viewer)
- [resourcedictionary](/questions/tagged/resourcedictionary) ← [resource-dictionary](/questions/tagged/resource-dictionary)
- [restructuredtext](/questions/tagged/restructuredtext) ← [restructured-text](/questions/tagged/restructured-text)
- [retinadisplay](/questions/tagged/retinadisplay) ← [retina-display](/questions/tagged/retina-display)
- [row-height](/questions/tagged/row-height) ← [rowheight](/questions/tagged/rowheight)
- [ruby-1.9](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9) ← [ruby1.9](/questions/tagged/ruby1.9)
- [ruby-on-rails-3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3) ← [ruby-on-rails3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails3)
- [ruby-on-rails-3-beta](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3-beta) ← [ruby-on-rails3beta](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails3beta)
- [scripting-bridge](/questions/tagged/scripting-bridge) ← [scriptingbridge](/questions/tagged/scriptingbridge)
- [sd-card](/questions/tagged/sd-card) ← [sdcard](/questions/tagged/sdcard)
- [serial-number](/questions/tagged/serial-number) ← [serialnumber](/questions/tagged/serialnumber)
- [server-side](/questions/tagged/server-side) ← [serverside](/questions/tagged/serverside)
- [service-broker](/questions/tagged/service-broker) ← [servicebroker](/questions/tagged/servicebroker)
- [servlet-filters](/questions/tagged/servlet-filters) ← [servletfilters](/questions/tagged/servletfilters)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [servletfilter](/questions/tagged/servletfilter) since [servlet-filter](/questions/tagged/servlet-filter) covers it.
- [session-scope](/questions/tagged/session-scope) ← [sessionscope](/questions/tagged/sessionscope)
- [shared-hosting](/questions/tagged/shared-hosting) ← [sharedhosting](/questions/tagged/sharedhosting)
- [shared-objects](/questions/tagged/shared-objects) ← [sharedobjects](/questions/tagged/sharedobjects)
- [sharepoint2007](/questions/tagged/sharepoint2007) ← [sharepoint-2007](/questions/tagged/sharepoint-2007)
- [sharepoint2010](/questions/tagged/sharepoint2010) ← [sharepoint-2010](/questions/tagged/sharepoint-2010)
- [sharpdevelop](/questions/tagged/sharpdevelop) ← [sharp-develop](/questions/tagged/sharp-develop)
- [shell-scripting](/questions/tagged/shell-scripting) (eliminate [shellscript](/questions/tagged/shellscript) since [shell-script](/questions/tagged/shell-script) covers it)
- [shopping-cart](/questions/tagged/shopping-cart) ← [shoppingcart](/questions/tagged/shoppingcart)
- [show-hide](/questions/tagged/show-hide) ← [showhide](/questions/tagged/showhide)
- [side-by-side](/questions/tagged/side-by-side) ← [sidebyside](/questions/tagged/sidebyside)
- [silverlight-3.0](/questions/tagged/silverlight-3.0) ← [silverlight3.0](/questions/tagged/silverlight3.0)
- [sms](/questions/tagged/sms) (eliminate [textmessages](/questions/tagged/textmessages) since [text-messages](/questions/tagged/text-messages) covers it)
- [solr](/questions/tagged/solr) (eliminate [apachesolr](/questions/tagged/apachesolr) since [apache-solr](/questions/tagged/apache-solr) covers it)
- [solutionexplorer](/questions/tagged/solutionexplorer) ← [solution-explorer](/questions/tagged/solution-explorer)
- [spellchecking](/questions/tagged/spellchecking) ← [spell-checking](/questions/tagged/spell-checking)
- [splash-screen](/questions/tagged/splash-screen) ← [splashscreen](/questions/tagged/splashscreen)
- [sproutcore-2](/questions/tagged/sproutcore-2) ← [sproutcore2](/questions/tagged/sproutcore2)
- [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) (eliminate [sqlquery](/questions/tagged/sqlquery) since [sql-query](/questions/tagged/sql-query) covers it)
- [sql-developer](/questions/tagged/sql-developer) ← [sqldeveloper](/questions/tagged/sqldeveloper)
- [sql-injection](/questions/tagged/sql-injection) ← [sqlinjection](/questions/tagged/sqlinjection)
- [sql-loader](/questions/tagged/sql-loader) ← [sqlloader](/questions/tagged/sqlloader)
- [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) ← [sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [ms-sql](/questions/tagged/ms-sql) since [mssql](/questions/tagged/mssql) covers it.
  **Note:** Also eliminate [ms-sqlserver](/questions/tagged/ms-sqlserver) since [mssql-server](/questions/tagged/mssql-server) covers it.
  **Note:** Also eliminate [ms-sql-server](/questions/tagged/ms-sql-server) since [mssql-server](/questions/tagged/mssql-server) covers it.
- [sql-server-2000](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2000) ← [sqlserver2000](/questions/tagged/sqlserver2000)
- [sql-server-2000](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2000) ← [sqlserver-2000](/questions/tagged/sqlserver-2000)
- [sql-server-2000](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2000) ← [sql-server2000](/questions/tagged/sql-server2000)
- [sql-server-2005](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005) ← [sqlserver2005](/questions/tagged/sqlserver2005)
- [sql-server-2005](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005) ← [sqlserver-2005](/questions/tagged/sqlserver-2005)
- [sql-server-2005](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005) ← [sql-server2005](/questions/tagged/sql-server2005)
- [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) ← [sqlserver2008](/questions/tagged/sqlserver2008)
- [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) ← [sqlserver-2008](/questions/tagged/sqlserver-2008)
- [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) ← [sql-server2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server2008)
- [sql-server-2011](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2011) ← [sqlserver2011](/questions/tagged/sqlserver2011)
- [sql-server-ce](/questions/tagged/sql-server-ce) (eliminate [sqlce](/questions/tagged/sqlce) since [sql-ce](/questions/tagged/sql-ce) covers it)
- [sql-server-ce](/questions/tagged/sql-server-ce) (eliminate [sqlcompact](/questions/tagged/sqlcompact) since [sql-compact](/questions/tagged/sql-compact) covers it)
- [sql-server-express](/questions/tagged/sql-server-express) (eliminate [sqlexpress](/questions/tagged/sqlexpress) since [sql-express](/questions/tagged/sql-express) covers it)
- [ssms](/questions/tagged/ssms) (eliminate [sql-server-management-stu](/questions/tagged/sql-server-management-stu) since [sqlservermanagementstudio](/questions/tagged/sqlservermanagementstudio) covers it)
- [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) ← [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow)
- [stack-trace](/questions/tagged/stack-trace) ← [stacktrace](/questions/tagged/stacktrace)
- [star-schema](/questions/tagged/star-schema) ← [starschema](/questions/tagged/starschema)
- [statemachine](/questions/tagged/statemachine) ← [state-machine](/questions/tagged/state-machine)
- [std-pair](/questions/tagged/std-pair) ← [stdpair](/questions/tagged/stdpair)
- [stop-words](/questions/tagged/stop-words) ← [stopwords](/questions/tagged/stopwords)
- [string-formatting](/questions/tagged/string-formatting) ← [stringformatting](/questions/tagged/stringformatting)
- [strongname](/questions/tagged/strongname) ← [strong-name](/questions/tagged/strong-name)
- [struts2](/questions/tagged/struts2) ← [struts-2](/questions/tagged/struts-2)
- [swingworker](/questions/tagged/swingworker) ← [swing-worker](/questions/tagged/swing-worker)
- [symfony-1.4](/questions/tagged/symfony-1.4) ← [symfony1.4](/questions/tagged/symfony1.4)
- [system-calls](/questions/tagged/system-calls) (eliminate [systemcall](/questions/tagged/systemcall) since [system-call](/questions/tagged/system-call) covers it)
- [tag-soup](/questions/tagged/tag-soup) ← [tagsoup](/questions/tagged/tagsoup)
- [task-queue](/questions/tagged/task-queue) ← [taskqueue](/questions/tagged/taskqueue)
- [team-build](/questions/tagged/team-build) ← [teambuild](/questions/tagged/teambuild)
- [text-files](/questions/tagged/text-files) ← [textfiles](/questions/tagged/textfiles)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [textfile](/questions/tagged/textfile) since [text-file](/questions/tagged/text-file) covers it.
- [text-formatting](/questions/tagged/text-formatting) ← [textformatting](/questions/tagged/textformatting)
- [text-processing](/questions/tagged/text-processing) ← [textprocessing](/questions/tagged/textprocessing)
- [tf-idf](/questions/tagged/tf-idf) ← [tfidf](/questions/tagged/tfidf)
- [tfsbuild](/questions/tagged/tfsbuild) ← [tfs-build](/questions/tagged/tfs-build)
- [third-party](/questions/tagged/third-party) ← [thirdparty](/questions/tagged/thirdparty)
- [threadpool](/questions/tagged/threadpool) ← [thread-pool](/questions/tagged/thread-pool)
- [timeout](/questions/tagged/timeout) ← [time-out](/questions/tagged/time-out)
- [time-series](/questions/tagged/time-series) ← [timeseries](/questions/tagged/timeseries)
- [time-zone](/questions/tagged/time-zone) ← [timezone](/questions/tagged/timezone)
- [tokyocabinet](/questions/tagged/tokyocabinet) ← [tokyo-cabinet](/questions/tagged/tokyo-cabinet)
- [tomcat-5.0](/questions/tagged/tomcat-5.0) ← [tomcat5.0](/questions/tagged/tomcat5.0)
- [tomcat-6.0](/questions/tagged/tomcat-6.0) ← [tomcat6.0](/questions/tagged/tomcat6.0)
- [tortoisehg](/questions/tagged/tortoisehg) ← [tortoise-hg](/questions/tagged/tortoise-hg)
- [transaction-log](/questions/tagged/transaction-log) ← [transactionlog](/questions/tagged/transactionlog)
- [try-catch](/questions/tagged/try-catch) ← [trycatch](/questions/tagged/trycatch)
- [tryparse](/questions/tagged/tryparse) ← [try-parse](/questions/tagged/try-parse)
- [tsql](/questions/tagged/tsql) ← [t-sql](/questions/tagged/t-sql)
- [twitter-api](/questions/tagged/twitter-api) ← [twitterapi](/questions/tagged/twitterapi)
- [type-safety](/questions/tagged/type-safety) ← [typesafety](/questions/tagged/typesafety)
- [u-boot](/questions/tagged/u-boot) ← [uboot](/questions/tagged/uboot)
- [ui-automation](/questions/tagged/ui-automation) ← [uiautomation](/questions/tagged/uiautomation)
- [ui-thread](/questions/tagged/ui-thread) ← [uithread](/questions/tagged/uithread)
- [unicode-string](/questions/tagged/unicode-string) ← [unicodestring](/questions/tagged/unicodestring)
- [unique-id](/questions/tagged/unique-id) ← [uniqueid](/questions/tagged/uniqueid)
- [unit-testing](/questions/tagged/unit-testing) (eliminate [unittest](/questions/tagged/unittest) since [unit-test](/questions/tagged/unit-test) covers it)
- [unit-testing](/questions/tagged/unit-testing) (eliminate [unittests](/questions/tagged/unittests) since [unit-tests](/questions/tagged/unit-tests) covers it)
- [unix-timestamp](/questions/tagged/unix-timestamp) (eliminate [unixtime](/questions/tagged/unixtime) since [unix-time](/questions/tagged/unix-time) covers it)
- [url-rewriting](/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) ← [urlrewriting](/questions/tagged/urlrewriting)
- [use-case](/questions/tagged/use-case) ← [usecase](/questions/tagged/usecase)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [usecases](/questions/tagged/usecases) since [use-cases](/questions/tagged/use-cases) covers it.
- [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) ← [useragent](/questions/tagged/useragent)
- [usercontrols](/questions/tagged/usercontrols) ← [user-controls](/questions/tagged/user-controls)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [user-control](/questions/tagged/user-control) since [usercontrol](/questions/tagged/usercontrol) covers it.
- [user-input](/questions/tagged/user-input) ← [userinput](/questions/tagged/userinput)
- [user-profile](/questions/tagged/user-profile) ← [userprofile](/questions/tagged/userprofile)
- [userscripts](/questions/tagged/userscripts) ← [user-scripts](/questions/tagged/user-scripts)
- [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8) ← [utf8](/questions/tagged/utf8)
- [value-type](/questions/tagged/value-type) (eliminate [valuetypes](/questions/tagged/valuetypes) since [value-types](/questions/tagged/value-types) covers it)
- [video-card](/questions/tagged/video-card) ← [videocard](/questions/tagged/videocard)
- [visual-path](/questions/tagged/visual-path) ← [visualpath](/questions/tagged/visualpath)
- [visual-c++](/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b) ← [visualc++](/questions/tagged/visualc%2b%2b)
- [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) ← [visualstudio](/questions/tagged/visualstudio)
- [visual-studio-2005](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2005) ← [visualstudio2005](/questions/tagged/visualstudio2005)
- [visual-studio-2008](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008) ← [visualstudio2008](/questions/tagged/visualstudio2008)
- [visual-studio-lightswitch](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-lightswitch) ← [visualstudiolightswitch](/questions/tagged/visualstudiolightswitch)
- [visual-studio-lightswitch](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-lightswitch) ← [visualstudio-lightswitch](/questions/tagged/visualstudio-lightswitch)
- [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) (eliminate [wcfservice](/questions/tagged/wcfservice) since [wcf-service](/questions/tagged/wcf-service) covers it)
- [wcf-data-services](/questions/tagged/wcf-data-services) ← [wcf-dataservices](/questions/tagged/wcf-dataservices)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [ado-net-dataservices](/questions/tagged/ado-net-dataservices) since [ado-net-data-services](/questions/tagged/ado-net-data-services) covers it.
- [web-application-project](/questions/tagged/web-application-project) ← [webapplicationproject](/questions/tagged/webapplicationproject)
- [web-applications](/questions/tagged/web-applications) ← [webapplication](/questions/tagged/webapplication)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [webapplication](/questions/tagged/webapplication) since [web-appliation](/questions/tagged/web-appliation) covers it.
  **Note:** Also eliminate [web-app](/questions/tagged/web-app) since [webapp](/questions/tagged/webapp) covers it.
- [webbrowser](/questions/tagged/webbrowser) ← [web-browser](/questions/tagged/web-browser)
  **Note:** Also eliminate incorrectly spelled [webbroswer](/questions/tagged/webbroswer).
- [webcontrols](/questions/tagged/webcontrols) ← [web-controls](/questions/tagged/web-controls)
- [web-deployment-project](/questions/tagged/web-deployment-project) ← [webdeploymentproject](/questions/tagged/webdeploymentproject)
- [web-design](/questions/tagged/web-design) ← [webdesign](/questions/tagged/webdesign)
- [web-development](/questions/tagged/web-development) ← [webdevelopment](/questions/tagged/webdevelopment)
- [web-hosting](/questions/tagged/web-hosting) ← [webhosting](/questions/tagged/webhosting)
- [weblogic-10.x](/questions/tagged/weblogic-10.x) ← [weblogic10.x](/questions/tagged/weblogic10.x)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [weblogic10](/questions/tagged/weblogic10) since [weblogic-10](/questions/tagged/weblogic-10) covers it.
- [weblogic-11g](/questions/tagged/weblogic-11g) (eliminate [weblogic11](/questions/tagged/weblogic11) since [weblogic-11](/questions/tagged/weblogic-11) covers it)
- [weblogic-8.x](/questions/tagged/weblogic-8.x) (eliminate [weblogic8](/questions/tagged/weblogic8) since [weblogic-8](/questions/tagged/weblogic-8) covers it)
- [weblogic-8.x](/questions/tagged/weblogic-8.x) (eliminate [weblogic8.1](/questions/tagged/weblogic8.1) since [weblogic-8.1](/questions/tagged/weblogic-8.1) covers it)
- [weblogic-9.x](/questions/tagged/weblogic-9.x) (eliminate [weblogic9](/questions/tagged/weblogic9) since [weblogic-9](/questions/tagged/weblogic-9) covers it)
- [webparts](/questions/tagged/webparts) ← [web-parts](/questions/tagged/web-parts)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [web-part](/questions/tagged/web-part) since [webpart](/questions/tagged/webpart) covers it.
- [web-scraping](/questions/tagged/web-scraping) ← [webscraping](/questions/tagged/webscraping)
- [web-services](/questions/tagged/web-services) ← [webservices](/questions/tagged/webservices)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [webservice](/questions/tagged/webservice) since [web-service](/questions/tagged/web-service) covers it.
- [web-site-project](/questions/tagged/web-site-project) ← [websiteproject](/questions/tagged/websiteproject)
- [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi) ← [win-api](/questions/tagged/win-api)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [win32-api](/questions/tagged/win32-api) since [win32api](/questions/tagged/win32api) covers it.
- [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7) ← [windows7](/questions/tagged/windows7)
- [windows-authentication](/questions/tagged/windows-authentication) ← [windowsauthentication](/questions/tagged/windowsauthentication)
- [windows-mobile](/questions/tagged/windows-mobile) ← [windowsmobile](/questions/tagged/windowsmobile)
- [windows-server-2008](/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008) (eliminate [server2008](/questions/tagged/server2008) since [server-2008](/questions/tagged/server-2008) covers it)
- [windows-services](/questions/tagged/windows-services) (eliminate [windowsservice](/questions/tagged/windowsservice) since [windows-service](/questions/tagged/windows-service) covers it)
- [windows-xp](/questions/tagged/windows-xp) ← [windowsxp](/questions/tagged/windowsxp)
- [word-count](/questions/tagged/word-count) ← [wordcount](/questions/tagged/wordcount)
- [word-wrap](/questions/tagged/word-wrap) ← [wordwrap](/questions/tagged/wordwrap)
- [windows-foundation-4](/questions/tagged/windows-foundation-4) (eliminate [wf4](/questions/tagged/wf4) since [wf-4](/questions/tagged/wf-4) covers it)
- [wpftoolkit](/questions/tagged/wpftoolkit) ← [wpf-toolkit](/questions/tagged/wpf-toolkit)
- [xml-binding](/questions/tagged/xml-binding) ← [xmlbinding](/questions/tagged/xmlbinding)
- [xml-parsing](/questions/tagged/xml-parsing) ← [xmlparsing](/questions/tagged/xmlparsing)
  **Note:** Also eliminate [xmlparser](/questions/tagged/xmlparser) since [xml-parser](/questions/tagged/xml-parser) covers it.
- [xml-rpc](/questions/tagged/xml-rpc) ← [xmlrpc](/questions/tagged/xmlrpc)
- [xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema) ← [xmlschema](/questions/tagged/xmlschema)
- [xml-serialization](/questions/tagged/xml-serialization) ← [xmlserialization](/questions/tagged/xmlserialization)
- [xml-simple](/questions/tagged/xml-simple) ← [xmlsimple](/questions/tagged/xmlsimple)
- [xna-4.0](/questions/tagged/xna-4.0) ← [xna4.0](/questions/tagged/xna4.0)
- [zen-coding](/questions/tagged/zen-coding) ← [zencoding](/questions/tagged/zencoding)
- [z-index](/questions/tagged/z-index) ← [zindex](/questions/tagged/zindex)
- [z-order](/questions/tagged/z-order) ← [zorder](/questions/tagged/zorder)

So, out of near 2,500 tag synonyms (and suggestions) that currently exist, almost **500 of them** only differ via one or more hyphens. A whopping 20% of our tag synonyms serve no purpose!

Comment: Post is excessively long – Community♦ 45 mins ago

Comment: Community flags are excessively long. WHAT'S WRONG WITH TL;DR, COMMUNITY?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128879/automagically-synonymise-a-non-existent-unhyphenated-tag-if-the-hyphenated-vers - the bit where I ask for this to be fixed at any rate.

Comment: Related: [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/135993#135993) — tag pairs that differ only by hyphenation and that are not synonyms. Please review them, discuss on meta if necessary, and either clean up manually or request a merge or a tag renaming.

Comment: Are we sure that this list contains only good synonyms (i.e. synonyms that were made because the tags mean the same thing, not because they look similar) and merged synonyms (which we can't save even if they're bad)?

Comment: @Shog9: Any chance someone will actually go through these? At the moment, it can only be done by moderators...

Comment: I'm not even sure what you were asking for here.

Comment: @animuson the above list is not consistent in handling hyphens vs non-hyphenated tags. I'm assuming from the arrows that you wish to merge the duplicate tag into the one pointed to by the arrow? IMHO, hyphens contribute to both human readability as well as search engine readability. Merging arbitrarily in both directions would just be annoying. Also you need a mechanism to prevent future re-growth of duplicate tags or your effort would be wasted.

Comment: @BenSwayne: The arrows indicate the current `master ← synonym` relationship for all the tags in the system, not necessarily which tag should exist in the grand scheme of things. Currently, you can no longer create tags which differ from another tag by only a hyphen, and a tag must exist in the system before you can suggest it as a synonym; so the loophole is closed. It's just a matter of cleaning up all the ones that have already gotten through.

Comment: @animuson Thanks, that better explains the arrows. My vote stills stands to prefer hyphens for readability. But hey, maybe that'll need its very own community discussion...

Comment: I also find the hyphenated versions far superior in readability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, that only took two hours. No big deal. Previously 28 pages of synonyms now only 23.

Farewell hyphen-only tag synonyms!