# Can't get rid of a tag synonym suggestion when the tag no longer exists

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

While compiling the list of [tag synonyms which differ by hyphens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147233/should-we-get-rid-of-all-the-tag-synonyms-which-differ-by-only-one-or-more-hyphe), I ran across this synonym suggestion:

[image: output ← ouput]

Obviously this should be rejected. It's a misspelling. Why on Earth would it need to be a synonym? However, the tag [output](/questions/tagged/output) doesn't seem to exist anymore and attempting to go to its [synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/output/synonyms) manually just results in a 404. **Shouldn't tag synonyms (suggested or already approved) automatically be killed off if the tag is destroyed?**