# Should adding orphaned/non-existent tags as synonyms be possible?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've noticed the [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) tag on the [recent tags list page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new). Seeing that [c-sharp](/questions/tagged/c-sharp) tag is [already a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c#/synonyms) of [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) I wanted to add [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) as a synonym as well. However, all questions using [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) seem to have been retagged, and thus [Tag synonyms for c#](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c#/synonyms) page opposed the attempt of adding a synonym from a non-existent tag. I decided to try forcing this anyway, mainly because of two reasons:

- existence of [c-sharp](/questions/tagged/c-sharp)
- fact that [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) showed up suggests that it's possible that it will occur again

So I did this:

1. I edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204454/enum-value-extraction) but apart from ordinary formatting fixes I added the [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) tag.
2. I successfully added this tag as a synonym of [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).
3. I edited the post again, removing the [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) tag. This was done fast enough to both edits merge into one edit, leaving no trace of [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) tag.
4. [As you can see](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/synonyms) [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) remains as a synonym suggestion.

*My question is*:

Is this a system flaw rendering the tag existence verification useless, that needs to be addressed? Maybe a synonym suggestion should disappear when the tag gets orphaned again? Or maybe adding orphaned/non-existent tags as synonyms should be possible?

*Side question*:

Am I a bad person for doing this?

Comment: Why would this need to be addressed or make you a bad person? I don't see an actual problem here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The question about being a bad person is partially a joke :) What I'm curious about, in other words, is the sense of the tag existence verification when proposing a synonym, when this can be easily overridden. Or maybe suggestions should disappear when tags become inactive?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also, I was a bit worried that maybe if such verification exists this is something that shouldn't be done.

Comment: Without a tag, there is nothing to add as a synonym; it is a basic prerequisite.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was not clear when calling this feature "tag verification". What it really does is verifying if any questions use the tag. And as I described in the question the tag exists, but is orphaned. Hence my confusion.

Comment: No, the tag *no longer exists*. The recent tags page is cached, but someone removed the misspelling.

Comment: @MartijnPieters According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/231717) it exists and will be deleted at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: Right, yes, the orphaned tag is to be cleaned up still. I wouldn't worry about this though.

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to create [tag:csharp] since [tag:c-sharp] exists. Tags that differ only by a hyphen are not needed, nor is a synonym. We [already had this problem before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147233/should-we-get-rid-of-all-the-tag-synonyms-which-differ-by-only-one-or-more-hyphe). Too many useless synonyms clogging up the pages. We don't need every possible hyphenation alteration to exist as a synonym.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for your explanation, and for the link. Shouldn't they be some kind of *automatic synonyms* to prevent them from occurring and confusing unaware people like me? :) Also, this seems to answer the question exactly, so could you post it as an answer?

Comment: That only answers your question in this specific case, though. In general, I would consider this a flaw. In fact, if you suggest a synonym and the tag later gets destroyed, [you can't even vote on the synonym suggestion anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147262/cant-get-rid-of-a-tag-synonym-suggestion-when-the-tag-no-longer-exists). That is an old question, though - not sure if it still works that way. I'm pretty sure Shog just killed that single synonym and they didn't fix the underlying issue.

Comment: @animuson Yes, seems like another instance of this issue. For me the case is resolved, not sure whether I should reword the question to be a bug report in the context you mention?

Comment: Also, thanks for @MartijnPieters for your time and explanations.