# Merge [svn-merge] > [svnmerge] and [svnexternal] > [svn-externals]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

It would be wise to [svn-merge](/questions/tagged/svn-merge) > [svnmerge](/questions/tagged/svnmerge) and [svnexternal](/questions/tagged/svnexternal) > [svn-externals](/questions/tagged/svn-externals).

Or we could make them synonyms.

There are a lot of questions tagged with both variants.

Comment: [Or we could **not** make them synonyms.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147233/should-we-get-rid-of-all-the-tag-synonyms-which-differ-by-only-one-or-more-hyphe) Merging is just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually re-tagged questions under [svnmerge](/questions/tagged/svnmerge) (~ 35) and [svnexternal](/questions/tagged/svnexternal) (~ 45). Now no question is using either of these 2 tags. [svnmerge](/questions/tagged/svnmerge) and [svnexternal](/questions/tagged/svnexternal) will be removed from the system within 24 hours when the [tag cleanup runs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40724/166025).